# How to fix wrong redirect utl 301 in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, varnish

I used htaccess to limited ip which can connect to admin and user login page.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
RewriteRule (admin|user)$ http://redirect_example.com [R=301,L]
```

But the problem here is I used 301 redirect which mean when I can't change url http://redirect_example.com to another url. It's has already cached. My curl -I http://example.com/user result:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 17 Feb 2017 03:46:19 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: max-age=1209600
Expires: Fri, 03 Mar 2017 03:46:19 GMT
Content-Length: 313
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Location: http://redirect_example.com
Age: 251965
X-Cache: HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 56
Connection: keep-alive
```

How do I change http://redirect_example.com to another url?

Answer (score 2):

Caused by Varnish. You should ban the cache by run the command:

```
varnishadm
```

Then ban the cache by domain:

```
ban req.http.host ~ "redirect_example.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just cached in your browser. Clear your browser cache. You can use 302 redirects while testing to help with this.

Comment: I think that's not cached in browser. Cause after delete 301 redirect in htaccess. I tried in private browser, browser of another computer but it still redirect to http://redirect_example.com

Comment: Well it won't be cached on the server unless you have something in place that could be doing that. Try restarting Apache just in case. Otherwise it could perhaps be cached by a proxy.

Comment: Would you mind giving me example of "something"? How do I check if it is cached on the server? Many thanks!

Comment: Some kind of caching on the server, or some proxy you have sat in between doing caching. If you had it, you would know about it. It's not very likely. Examine your setup carefully, it's likely something simple you missed.

Comment: Does memcached or varnish store this kind of cache?

Comment: Oh yes, because of varnish. I run varnishadm ban and now it work just like normal. Thank for your hint!